# Vlc.DotNet.Forms falla de video

Tags: c#, windows-forms, .net

estoy realizando un Activex con C# utilizando las librerías de VLC para reproducir un rtsp usando los servicios de Onvif. Al hacerlo la primer vez todo marcha bien
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
pero al detener la imagen y volver a cargar el rtsp la imagen se vuelve verde o distorcionada
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el botón de stop he intentado quitar el vlccontrol y volverl a ponerlo antes de cargar el rtsp pero me sigue sucediendo lo mismo y no se que pueda ser.

Este es mi código:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace OnvifBCWF{
public partial class UserControl1: UserControl
{
    Media.Profile[] perfiles;
    Media.MediaClient med;
    string address;
    string user;
    string password;
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void UserControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    public void StopCamera() {
        vlcCamera.Stop();
        vlcCamera.ResetMedia();
        vlcCamera.Refresh();
        perfiles = null;
        med = null;
        address = null;
        user = null;
        password = null;
    }

    public void Snapshot(string ruta) {
        ruta += DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmss") + ".png";
        vlcCamera.TakeSnapshot(ruta);
    }

    public void Start(string ip, string usu, string pass)
    {
        address = ip;
        user = usu;
        password = pass;
        vlcCamera.Stop();
        vlcCamera.Refresh();
        listBox.Items.Clear();
        try
        {
            var services = traeServicios();
            var xmedia2 = services.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Namespace == "http://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl");
            if (xmedia2 != null)
            {
                listBox.Items.Clear();

                try
                {
                    perfiles = traePerfiles(xmedia2.XAddr);
                    button1_Click(null, null);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
                }
                //if (perfiles != null) foreach (var p in perfiles) listBox.Items.Add(p.Name);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        }
    }

    public Media.Profile[] traePerfiles(string uri)
    {
        Media.Profile[] resultado;
        try
        {
            PasswordDigestBehavior behavior = new PasswordDigestBehavior(user, password);
            med = new Media.MediaClient(WsdlBinding, new EndpointAddress(uri));
            med.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(behavior);
            resultado = med.GetProfiles();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            try
            {
                med = new Media.MediaClient(WsdlBinding2, new EndpointAddress(uri));
                med.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = user;
                med.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;
                resultado = med.GetProfiles();
            }
            catch (Exception exx)
            {
                resultado = null;
                MessageBox.Show(exx.Message + exx.StackTrace);
            }

        }
        return resultado;
    }


    public device.Service[] traeServicios()
    {
        device.Service[] resultado;
        try
        {
            PasswordDigestBehavior behavior = new PasswordDigestBehavior(user, password);
            var device = new device.DeviceClient(WsdlBinding, new EndpointAddress("http://" + address + "/onvif/device_service"));
            device.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(behavior);
            resultado = device.GetServices(false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            try
            {
                var device = new device.DeviceClient(WsdlBinding2, new EndpointAddress("http://" + address + "/onvif/device_service"));
                device.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = user;
                device.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;
                resultado = device.GetServices(false);
            }
            catch (Exception exx)
            {
                resultado = null;
                MessageBox.Show(exx.Message + exx.StackTrace);
            }
        }
        return resultado;
    }

    System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding WsdlBinding2
    {
        get
        {
            HttpTransportBindingElement httpTransport = new HttpTransportBindingElement();
            httpTransport.AuthenticationScheme = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.Basic;
            return new CustomBinding(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap12WSAddressing10, Encoding.UTF8), httpTransport);
        }
    }
    System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding WsdlBinding
    {
        get
        {
            HttpTransportBindingElement httpBinding = new HttpTransportBindingElement();

            httpBinding.AuthenticationScheme = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.Digest;

            var messageElement = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();

            messageElement.MessageVersion = MessageVersion.CreateVersion(EnvelopeVersion.Soap12, AddressingVersion.None);

            CustomBinding bind = new CustomBinding(messageElement, httpBinding);
            return bind;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (perfiles != null)
        {
            string[] xxx = address.Split(':');
            string portNo = "80";
            if (xxx.Length > 1)
            {
                portNo = xxx[1];
            };
            Media.StreamSetup streamSetup = new Media.StreamSetup
            {
                Stream = Media.StreamType.RTPMulticast
            };
            Media.Transport trs = new Media.Transport
            {
                Protocol = Media.TransportProtocol.HTTP
            };
            streamSetup.Transport = trs;
            try
            {
                var uri = med.GetStreamUri(streamSetup, perfiles[0].token);
                string config = address;
                config = config + "|" + user;
                config = config + "|" + password;
                config = config + "|" + uri.Uri;

                AddCamera(config);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
            }
        };
    }


    private void MediaPlayer_Log(object sender, Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcMediaPlayerLogEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("libVlc : {0} {1} @ {2}", e.Level, e.Message, e.Module));
    }

    private void OnVlcControlNeedsLibDirectory(object sender, Vlc.DotNet.Forms.VlcLibDirectoryNeededEventArgs e)
    {
        var currentAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
        var currentDirectory = new FileInfo(currentAssembly.Location).DirectoryName;
        if (currentDirectory == null)
            return;
        if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
            e.VlcLibDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(System.IO.Path.Combine(currentDirectory, @"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC"));
        else
            e.VlcLibDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(System.IO.Path.Combine(currentDirectory, @"D:\temp\src\onvifex\Vlc.DotNet-develop\lib\x64"));
    }

    public void AddCamera(string config)
    {
        string[] z = config.Split('|');
        try
        {

            vlcCamera.VlcLibDirectoryNeeded += OnVlcControlNeedsLibDirectory;
            vlcCamera.Log += MediaPlayer_Log;
            try
            {
                string[] xxx = z[0].Split(':');
                string portNo = "554";
                if (xxx.Length > 1)
                {
                    portNo = xxx[1];
                };
                var uri = z[3];
                ////                    textBox.Text = uri;
                uri = uri.Replace("http://", "rtsp://");
                string[] options = {
                                ":rtsp-http",
                                ":rtsp-http-port="+portNo ,
                                ":rtsp-user=" + z[1],
                                ":rtsp-pwd=" + z[2],
                };
                var ur = new Uri(uri);
                vlcCamera.Play(ur);
                //vlcCamera.ResetMedia();
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                int try3 = 6;
                var estado = vlcCamera.State;
                do
                {
                    estado = vlcCamera.State;
                    if (estado != Vlc.DotNet.Core.Interops.Signatures.MediaStates.Playing)
                    {
                        if (--try3 == 0) break;
                        vlcCamera.Stop();
                        vlcCamera.Play(new Uri(uri), options);
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                } while (estado != Vlc.DotNet.Core.Interops.Signatures.MediaStates.Playing);
                if (estado != Vlc.DotNet.Core.Interops.Signatures.MediaStates.Playing)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No se pudo cargar: " + estado);
                };
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            }

            listBox.Items.Clear();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        }

    }

}
}
```

Nose si sea la libreria de vlc o que podria ser, agradezco sus comentarios y sugerencias.

Answer (score 0):

La solución es que solo cambié el Streamtype de RTPMulticast a RTPUnicast
en:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (perfiles != null)
    {
        string[] xxx = address.Split(':');
        string portNo = "80";
        if (xxx.Length > 1)
        {
            portNo = xxx[1];
        };
        Media.StreamSetup streamSetup = new Media.StreamSetup
        {
            Stream = Media.StreamType.RTPUnicast
        };
        Media.Transport trs = new Media.Transport
        {
            Protocol = Media.TransportProtocol.HTTP
        };
        streamSetup.Transport = trs;
        try
        {
            var uri = med.GetStreamUri(streamSetup, perfiles[0].token);
            string config = address;
            config = config + "|" + user;
            config = config + "|" + password;
            config = config + "|" + uri.Uri;

            AddCamera(config);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
        }
    };
}
```